GEE Layer error_ Computation timed out
I am trying to extract water mask over a large collection of rapideye images using Google Earth Engine. I developed this script in the code editor of Google Earth Engine, which works perfectly for a small set of images.
But when I try to increase the number of images to over 10, I get this error:

S2_water_all: Layer error: Computation timed out.

var roi = BLH.geometry().buffer(100);
Map.centerObject(roi,10)
var allArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 10e15,
}).get("area");
print("roiArea", allArea)

//去云
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
              .copyProperties(image) 
              .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

//同日期拼接
function mosaicByDate(imcol) {
  var unique_dates = imcol
    .aggregate_array('system:time_start')
    .map(function(date) {
      return ee.Date(date).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
    })
    .distinct();
  // 使用内置的 reduce 方法进行镶嵌
  print('Unique Dates:', unique_dates);
  var mosaic_imlist = unique_dates.map(function(d) {
    var date = ee.Date(d);
    var filtered = imcol.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'));
    var mosaic = filtered.mosaic();
    return mosaic.set({
      'system:time_start': date.millis(),
      'system:id': date.format('YYYY-MM-dd')
    });
  });
  return ee.ImageCollection(mosaic_imlist);
}

// 计算归一化差值指数并添加为新的波段
function MNDWI(image, band1, band2) {
  var mndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['green','swir1']).rename('mndwi');
  var formattedDate = image.get('Date');
  return mndwi.set('Date', formattedDate)
              .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}

//OTSU计算阈值
function otsu(histogram) {
  var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
  var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
  var size = means.length().get([0]);
  var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var mean = sum.divide(total);
  var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
  var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
    var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        .divide(aCount);
    var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
    var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
    return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
           bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
  });
  return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
}


function calWaterMask(image){
  var image = image.select("mndwi");
  var histogram = image.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(),
      geometry: roi,
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    });
  var threshold = otsu(histogram.get("mndwi"));
  var mask = image.gte(threshold);
  return image.addBands(mask.rename('watermask'));
}

function removeSmallPatch(image) {
  // 计算连接区域中的像素数量，使用8连通规则
  var mask = image.select('watermask').connectedPixelCount({
    maxSize: 1000,
    eightConnected: true
  });
  // 过滤掉小于阈值的区域
  var largePatches = mask.gte(100);
  // 更新掩膜以仅保留大于阈值的区域
  var filteredImage = image.updateMask(largePatches);
  // 返回处理后的图像
  return filteredImage;
}

// 将Nodata值设置为0
function fillMaskedAreas(image, roi) {
    var modifiedImage = image.where(image.eq(0), 1)
                                   .where(image.eq(1), 2);
    var filledImage = modifiedImage.unmask(0);
    return filledImage;
}

function Caoccurence_th(image, waterOccurence, roi) {
    // Apply water occurrence mask to image
    var image = waterOccurence.updateMask(image.eq(2));
    // Reduce region to histogram
    var image_hist = image.reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram({ maxBuckets: Math.pow(2, 8) }),
        geometry: roi,
        scale: 10,
        maxPixels: 1e9,
    });
    // Calculate average list values and weighted sum
    var average_list1 = ee.Dictionary(ee.Dictionary(image_hist).get('watermask')).get("bucketMeans");
    var average_list1 = ee.List(average_list1);
    var average_list2 = ee.Dictionary(ee.Dictionary(image_hist).get('watermask')).get('histogram');
    var average_list2 = ee.List(average_list2);
    var average_list3 = ee.Array(average_list1).multiply(ee.Array(average_list2));
    var average_list3_sum = average_list3.toList().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
    // Calculate count threshold
    var count_th = ee.Number(average_list3_sum).multiply(0.17);
    // Calculate accumulative sum of average list
    function accumulativeAdd(item, list) {
        var previous = ee.Number(ee.List(list).get(-1));
        var added = ee.Number(item).add(previous);
        return ee.List(list).add(added);
    }
    var average_list2_accum = ee.List(average_list2.iterate(accumulativeAdd, ee.List([0]))).flatten().remove(0);
    // Filter accumulative list based on count threshold
    var average_list2_accum_filter = average_list2_accum.map(function(item) {
        return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number(item).gt(count_th), 1, 0);
    });
    // Get the index of the first occurrence of value 1
    var first_index = average_list2_accum_filter.indexOf(1);
    // Calculate occurrence threshold
    var occurence_th = average_list1.get(first_index);
    // Return the occurrence threshold value
    var imageWithAttribute = image.set('occurrence_threshold', occurence_th);
    return imageWithAttribute;
}

function processImage(image) {
  var processedImage = Caoccurence_th(image, waterOccurence, roi);
  return processedImage;
}

function fill(image) {
    var processedImage = processImage(image);
    var occurrenceThreshold = ee.Number(processedImage.get('occurrence_threshold'));
    var thresholdImage = ee.Image.constant(occurrenceThreshold);
    var waterCorrect = waterOccurence.gte(thresholdImage);
    var correctedImage = image.where(waterCorrect, ee.Image.constant(2));
    return correctedImage;
}

function calculateArea(image) {
    var mask = image.eq(2);
    var pixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea();
    var area = pixelArea.multiply(mask);
    var areaDict = area.reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
        geometry: roi, 
        scale: 10,  
        maxPixels: 1e13,
        tileScale: 16
    });
    var areaValue = ee.Number(areaDict.get('area')).divide(1000000);
    var imageWithArea = image.set('area_filled', areaValue);
    return imageWithArea;
}

//可视化参数，按843波段合成                
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['swir1', 'nir', 'red'],
};
//按矢量边界裁剪
function roiClip(image){
  return image.clip(roi)
}

//时间范围
var startDate = ee.Date('2018-1-1');
var endDate = ee.Date('2018-5-1');
var landsatBands = ["B2","B3","B4","B8","B11","B12"];
var IsBands = ['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','swir2'];
var S2 = sentinel.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
           .filterBounds(roi)
           //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 50))
           .map(maskS2clouds)
           .select(landsatBands,IsBands)
           .map(roiClip)
           .sort('system:time_start');
Map.addLayer(S2.first(), rgbVis, 'RGB'); 
print("raw",S2)
// S2 =mosaicByDate(S2);
//print("mosaicbyday",S2)

var S2_mndwi = S2.map(MNDWI) 
Map.addLayer(S2_mndwi.first(),{},"S2_mndwi");

var filterCondition = function(image) {
    var realArea = ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(image.select(0).mask()).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: roi,
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 10e15,
    }).get("area"); 
    var areaRatio = ee.Number(realArea).divide(allArea);
    return image.set('area_ratio', areaRatio);
};

var S2_mndwi_filtered = S2_mndwi.map(filterCondition).filter(ee.Filter.gt('area_ratio', 0.05));

var S2_mndwi_ostu = S2_mndwi_filtered.map(calWaterMask).select('watermask').map(removeSmallPatch)
    S2_mndwi_ostu = S2_mndwi_ostu.map(fillMaskedAreas).map(roiClip)
Map.addLayer(S2_mndwi_ostu.first(),{},"OSTU");

var handThreshold = 20
var hand = ee.Image('users/gena/GlobalHAND/30m/hand-1000').resample('bilinear').clip(roi)
hand = hand .reproject({
                crs: hand.projection(),
                scale: 10 
    });
var handFiltered = hand.gt(handThreshold).selfMask();
Map.addLayer(handFiltered, { palette: ['black'] }, 'handFiltered')

var S2_mndwi_ostu_1 = S2_mndwi_ostu.map(function(image) {
    var filledImage = image.where(handFiltered.eq(1),0)
    return filledImage;
}).map(roiClip);

var visParam_fre = {'min':0,'max':1,'palette':['black','blue']};
var waterOccurence= waterOccurence_BL.rename('watermask').resample('bilinear').clip(roi)
waterOccurence = waterOccurence .reproject({
                crs:waterOccurence.projection(),
                scale: 10 
    });
Map.addLayer(waterOccurence,visParam_fre,'waterOccurence');

var S2_water = S2_mndwi_ostu_1.map(function(img){
  var mask = img.eq(2);
  var pixelArea = ee.Image.pixelArea();
  var area = pixelArea.multiply(mask);
  var areaDict = area.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: roi, 
      scale: 10,  
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      tileScale: 16
  });
  var missMask = ee.Number(areaDict.get('area'));
  var missMask_th = ee.Number(missMask).divide(allArea);
  return img.set("missMask_th",missMask_th);
});

var S2_water_filter_0 = S2_water.filter(ee.Filter.gt("missMask_th",0.95));
    S2_water_filter_0 = S2_water_filter_0.map(calculateArea);
print("S2_water_filter_0",S2_water_filter_0); 
var S2_water_filter_1 = S2_water.filter(ee.Filter.gte("missMask_th",0.05))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.lt("missMask_th",0.95));
print("S2_water_filter_1",S2_water_filter_1);   

var S2_water_fill = S2_water_filter_1.map(fill);
print('S2_water_fill:', S2_water_fill);
Map.addLayer(S2_water_fill.first(), {}, 'S2_water_fill');
S2_water_fill = S2_water_fill.map(calculateArea);

var S2_water_all = S2_water_filter_0.merge(S2_water_fill).sort("system:time_start")
print('S2_water_all:', S2_water_all);
Map.addLayer(S2_water_all.first(), {}, 'S2_water_all');

var featureCollection = S2_water_all.map(function(image) {
  // 获取提取的日期字符串
  var Date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var area = ee.Number(image.get('area_filled'));
  // 使用提取的日期作为Feature的属性
  return ee.Feature(null, {'Date': Date, 'area': area});
});

// 创建一个图表，显示提取的日期、原始面积和填充后的面积数据
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: featureCollection,
  xProperty: 'Date',
  yProperties:'area'
}).setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Water Area',
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Area'},
    pointSize: 5,
    series: {
      0: {color: 'blue'},
      1: {color: 'green'}
    }
});

// 设置图表的大小
chart.style().set({
  width: '500px',
  height: '400px'
});
print(chart);

